# How to make all images in Views display at same dimensions

Tags: views, theming

My preview (thumbnail) images won't seem to display on my Views 3*16 grid page and my edits in the image Filed don't seem to make a different.  How do I ensure and force the Field image (cell) in the said Views page to show all the image content consistent in size? The image is a link to the actual page Node content. I'm probably missing something trivial, but you help would much appreciated.

(I'm using Bootstrap 3, Views 3.7 on Drupal 7.28).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to chose an image style for your images. Set up your grid image style first under admin/config/media/image-styles

Comment: Excellent! Thank you that is the answer. I needed to set my Views Grid images to be ie 220px*200px. What I did was create a new 'Style' as stated above setting the dimension in the 'style effects' with the 'Resize and Crop' feature which then made all my images the same size. Then from my Views Image Field setting, set the style type to my new Grid Image setting. Voila. Thanks again buddy for your tip. Worked a treat. (-:

Comment: Also, this tip also worked to fix the image style on the custom Node type page that I had created, better still I can create a second Image style for that page. thanks @ig016